# Creating pg_dump file in OS terminal

Tags: sql, macos, postgresql, pgadmin, pg-dump

I tried to find it out on google, but didn't worked well so I hope to find help here! :)

I am trying to create a pg_dump file on mac osx but there is no \bin folder as needed in cmd on windows.
My question is how to create the pg_dump file on mac osx?

Best regards!

Comment: Could You type `whereis pg_dump` in the text console?

Comment: terminal doesn't show anything

Comment: If You have PostgreSQL installed, there should be a pg_dump file somewhere in the filesystem. The default installation dir on a POSIX is `/usr/local/pgsql/bin`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/install-short.html It is probably different for You, though. You have to search or tell How You installed the PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where you installed PostgreSQL from. If its the .dmg from postgresql.org then the command will be in:

`/Library/PostgreSQL/<version eg. 9.6>/bin`

This is not in the PATH so you will have to either `cd` to the directory and run the command or add the directory to the PATH.

Another option is to search for the command with:

`cd /`

`find ./ -name pg_dump`

Comment: Thanks for answer Fabrizio! i tried to add this path which first of all i couldnt find to pg admin but it gives me error when i try to backup file from pg_admin gui.

Comment: Have you set the version correctly? Which version of PostgreSQL are you running?

Comment: I got the 9.6 version

Comment: OK. From where did you install it?

Comment: https://www.pgadmin.org/download/macos4.php from this site, when i try to make a backup i got an error that the file does not exist, but found out how to make it in terminal i hope it works at is supposed to. thanks for your help :)

Comment: OK. Where is the server?? Is it on the same machine or on a remote machine?